# Angular2 with Selenium or Protractor

Tags: angular, selenium

Could Selenium be used with Angular2 or is Protractor the only option? Following is the HTML code of Angular2 app generated by AngularCLI.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DwNg2App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Following is the HTML code of component but I do not see this HTML in the generated page!

```
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="http://angularjs.blogspot.ca/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I find elements etc using Selenium if I the page doesnt have these elements? This made me wonder if Selenium is not the right tool for Angular2

Comment: Of course you can use selenium. Perhaps you need to wait for Angular to complete initialization. `<app-root></app-root>` only gets children when the root component is created.

Comment: sorry, I do not follow. The HTML code above is of the deployed app on AWS S3. The this is the HTML browser has, how will Selenium find the different HTML elements?

Comment: Selenium only finds what's there. My assumption is, that if it's not there, then this is because Angular didn't create it (yet). Either Angular is not starting to run for some reason or your selenium action is too early and Angular isn't yet done initializing the page (rendering the root component)

Comment: If you are looking to generate the page in code and then test it then selenium is not for you. Selenium should only be used when your page can render in browser and you can see those elements

Comment: My app is in http://angularupload.manuchadha.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ I just noticed that I am able to see the page in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE!!

Comment: maybe I have a much older version of these browsers!!